# Remove www from subdomains in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, redirect, subdomain

I have a domain domain.org

I am adding SSL, unforunately a lot of subdomain where created as "www.subdomain" and it is way more expensive to create certificate to multiple 3 level subdomains.

Is it possible to redirect www.subdomain.domain.org to subdomain.domain.org without redirecting for www.domain.org?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, check out the Apache 2.2 doc for mod_rewrite:

[Apache Module mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Also check this serverfault post: [Redirect, Change URLs or Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache - Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever)

But remember. SSL is negotiated before URL rewriting, so you will get a CN mismatch error on your browsers.

You can consider buying an SSL wildcard certificate, which covers all subdomains whitin a domain. But this certificates are more expensive than traditional certs.

Regards